# Fill 2D array columns with unique random numbers Java

Tags: arrays, random, 2d

This is a project for school. It is a Bingo game, and the instructions for the part I'm working on are to fill a Bingo card using a 2D array. The first (B) column must have random numbers from 1 to 15 with no numbers repeating. The second (I) column must have randoms from 16 to 30, third (N) from 31 - 45 and so on. I have it set up to fill and display the cards, but I'm getting repeats. I can't figure out how to check the random number against each row in the specific column to see if it was already used, and change that number as needed. I understand what I have to do logically, but I don't know how to code it. Under the B section is where I've been trying to get started. I've tried numerous things, but to no avail. Here's my code, please help:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class BingoCard
{
    Random randNum = new Random();
    int[][] numberCard = new int[5][5];
    boolean[][] shadowCard = new boolean[5][5];

    /** Constructor */
    // set up 2D arrays for bingo cards, and card comparison 
    public BingoCard()
    {
    // create number card
    // fill B column with random numbers from 1 to 15
    for(int i = 0; i < numberCard.length; i++)
    {
        this.numberCard[i][0] = randInt(1, 15);
        // check for double numbers and recall a random
        while(this.numberCard[i][0] != numberCard[i][0])
        {  
            i++;
        }
        if(this.numberCard[i][0] == numberCard[i][0])
        {
            numberCard[i][0] = randInt(1, 15);
        }
    }
    // fill I column with random numbers from 16 to 30
    for(int j = 0; j < numberCard.length; j++)
    {
        numberCard[j][1] = randInt(16, 30);
        // check for double numbers and recall a random

    }
    // fill N column with random numbers from 31 to 45
    for(int k = 0; k < numberCard.length; k++)
    {
        numberCard[k][2] = randInt(31, 45);
        numberCard[2][2] = 0; // free space
        // check for double numbers and recall a random

    }  
    // fill G column with random numbers from 46 to 60   
    for(int m = 0; m < numberCard.length; m++)
    {
        numberCard[m][3] = randInt(46, 60);
        // check for double numbers and recall a random

    }
    // fill O column with random numbers from 61 to 75
    for(int n = 0; n < numberCard.length; n++)
    {
        numberCard[n][4] = randInt(61, 75);
        // check for double numbers and recall a random

    }

    // create shadow card to compare to main card
    for(int i = 0; i < shadowCard.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            shadowCard[i][j] = false;
            shadowCard[2][2] = true;
        }
    }

    }

/** Methods */

// method to generate a random number in intervals
private int randInt(int min, int max) 
{
    int random;
    random = randNum.nextInt(max - min) + min;
    return random;
}

// method to print the numberCard
public String printNumCard()
{
    String string = "";
    for(int row = 0; row < numberCard.length; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < numberCard[row].length; col++)
        {
            System.out.print(numberCard[row][col] + "  ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    return string;
 }




    /** main method for testing */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BingoCard bc = new BingoCard();
        bc.printNumCard();

    } 


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set up vectors filled with values in the allowable ranges, and [shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm) them. Then select the first N of the shuffled set, where N is the number of values in the given column of the bingo card, and copy them to that column.